# 404 error when trying to upload crash to hockeyapp

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, hockeyapp

I'm trying to upload crash manually to HockeyApp using [public API](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/api/api-crashes#-u-post-api-2-apps-app_id-crashes-upload-u-). When calling the api link using Postman and uploading crash.log file it works fine but when I try to do the same from C# code I get 404 error.

Here is my code:

```
string log = ""; //log content
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    var stringContent = new StringContent(log);
    stringContent.Headers.ContentType = System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain");

    content.Add(stringContent, "log", "crash.log");

    var response = await this.client.PostAsync("https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/[APP_ID]/crashes/upload", content);
}
```

I was using WireShark to analyse the request that Postman is sending and tried to make mine look exactly the same. The only difference I see is that request from C# code has filename* field in Content-Disposition for the attachment while the one from Postman doesn't:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="log"; filename="crash.log"; filename*=utf-8''%22crash.log%22
```

It might be worth mentioning that the code is written in portable library in Xamarin project.

Comment: Just to make sure, the URL normally has `[APP_ID]` replaced with a proper HockeyApp App ID, right? :)

Comment: Yes, of course ;)

Comment: I would suggest to open a support ticket with HockeyApp directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Lukas Spieß sugestion I asked the [question](https://support.hockeyapp.net/discussions/problems/74325-404-error-when-trying-to-upload-crash-to-hockeyapp-from-c) on HockeyApp support. Apparently they don't handle quotes in the boundary header. The one thing I missed comparing Postman request and mine.

Here is the solution:

```
var contentTypeString = content.Headers.ContentType.ToString().Replace("\"", "");

content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", contentTypeString);
```

Comment: where do I have to put this code because it doesn't work ?